# Moving enemy in 2D?

Tags: java, image, geometry

Basically I want to move my enemy from one position to another.

There starting position is not a problem... neither is the place where they are suppose to go.

The problem lies with the how they get there. With the code I wrote they just teleport off the map.

So I am not even going to post it. Using triangles... what would be the most efficient way to get them from point A to point B?

Lets say point A is 10, 10; and point B is 123, 349. But there is also the chance that A will be B and B will be A. So it also has to deal with negatives.

Now the last thing that complicates the matter is that it moves between 1 and 5 pixels every time it repaints... so if it goes over the position I am not sure how to check to see if its in the general area.

Thanks! Btw I don't need full code... just IDEAS!!! I can code myself. Thank you!!!

current code:

```
                if (enemyList.length > 0) {
                for (int[] x : enemyList) {
                    double changeX;
                    double changeY;
                    //if already in spot, anounce it
                    if (x[0] == x[2] && x[1] == x[3]) {
                        x[2] = -1;
                        x[3] = -1;
                    }
                    //if anounced generate new spot of interest
                    if (x[2] == -1 || x[3] == -1) {
                        x[2] = generateRandom(0, 550);
                        x[3] = generateRandom(0, 400);
                    }
                    //find distance from target and move there
                    int _y = x[1] - x[3];
                    int _x = x[0] - x[2];
                    if (_x > _y) {
                        changeX = _x / _y;
                        changeY = _y / _y;
                    } else {
                        changeY = _y / _x;
                        changeX = _x / _x;
                    }
                    changeY = changeY * generateRandom(0, 10);
                    changeX = changeX * generateRandom(0, 10);
                    //change physical position
                    x[0] += (int) changeX;
                    x[1] += (int) changeY;
                }
            }
```

Comment: What does your current algorithm look like?

Comment: @Justin there you go, thats what I have now... the enemyList stores 4 variables... currentX, currentY, futureX, futureY... future means destination... hope that helps you help me  :)

Comment: I'm not sure of the specifics in the Java environment, but this is typically done with linear interpolation.  From a quick google search it appears there may be a class for this: http://multigraph.sourceforge.net/multigraph/javadoc/multigraph/LinearInterpolator.html

Comment: @willytate could you please explain what linear interpolation is? I have a strong feeling that I will not understand it if I search google and was hoping you could put it in simple terms. I will search google anyways, but am looking forward to your reply. Thank you so much for the hint btw!

Comment: Basically, given two points start(x,y) and finish(x`,y`) it calculates the line between these two points and will moves your object across this line based on a weight value between 0 and 1.  The weight value should be looked at as a percentage.  As you increase the weight the object will move across the line from start to finish.  I'm familiar with it through microsoft's XNA studio `MathHelper.Lerp()` function.  Sorry I couldn't provide more Java specific assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code it looks like your enemy will sort of wiggle to its destination in maybe a curved fashion, but it's hard to tell just by inspection.  Maybe you just need to swap your source and destination because it looks like you may just have it backwards:

```
int _y = x[3] - x[1];
int _x = x[2] - x[0];
```

Is this what you intended, or should it make a beeline?

```
speed = 5; // "pixels" per frame
deltaX = destX - sourceX;
deltaY = destY - sourceY;
distance = sqrt(deltaX^2 + deltaY^2);

moveX = speed / distance * deltaX;
moveY = speed / distance * deltaY;

newX = sourceX + moveX;
newY = sourceY + moveY;
```

I used *similar triangles* to calculate `moveX` and `moveY`.  Note the square root is slow, but that may be ok for your purposes... once you have it working, there are ways to optimize out the square root.

Comment: tried to make it strait as possible... and later when I update the game make it sometimes strait and sometimes curved...

Comment: The above pseudocode is a "straight" algorithm that will move it 5 units (on the hypotenuse) toward the target coordinates.

Comment: @Justin thank you, but why do you need distance? wouldn't that make it change speed as it was going towards the target destination?

Comment: No, you divide by distance because of similar triangles (http://www.mathopenref.com/similartriangles.html).  If I am `distance` away and I want to move `speed` amount toward it.  I need to proportionately move `moveX` out of `deltaX` in the X direction, and same with Y.  Because of similar triangles, `distance / speed = deltaX / moveX`.  I am just solving for `moveX`.

Comment: @Justin the move X and the move Y are way to big of numbers... they just fly off the screen... I tried adjusting the speed...but its still ridiculous...

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in a debugger to see what is happening?